# Countdown script not starting countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, countdown

Can someone please tell me why the countdown function is not working properly (the countdown is not starting in the div with the I.D. "countdown").  Probably something real simple, but Javascript isn't my forte.  This is the countdown plugin I am using: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link href="./css/web-style-second.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="chrome://mozbar/skin/css/injected.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a name="top"></a>
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">  

<div class="center">
    <center>
        <div></div>
    </center>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {
    $('#countdown').countdown({
        until: '14min+20sec',
        format: 'MS',
        layout: '{mnn}min  ' + '{snn}sec  ',
        onExpiry: function() {
            $(".hidden").css("display", "block");
        }
    });
});
</script>

<div class="time_box"> 
    <h3 class="italic">When The Clock Hits Zero ... </h3> 
    <h4 class="hasCountdown" id="countdown">14min  20sec  </h4>  
</div>

<form name="signupFrm" id="signupFrm" action="#" method="post" class="hidden">
    <div>
        <div class="yellow_red">
            <h1></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            <a href="https://www.testing.com" class="btn_buy_now">
            Get Started</a>
        </div>
        <input name="submit" value="submit" type="hidden">
        <p class="mb_5">&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="fnote justify">
</div>


    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are missing the "jQuery Countdown CSS" reference

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `$(function () ...)` script into the `<head>` tag of your HTML page. This way, the countdown will be initiated once the DOM has fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you are missing the reference to the "jQuery Countdown CSS". In the [usage instructions of the plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) it says:

> Download and include the jQuery Countdown CSS and JavaScript in the
>   head section of your page. @import
>   "jquery.countdown.css";

But you can still make it work without the "jQuery Countdown CSS" if you remove the `class` attribute from the `<h4>` element with the id "countdown", like this:

```
<div class="time_box"> 
    <h3 class="italic">When The Clock Hits Zero ... </h3> 
    <h4 id="countdown">14min  20sec  </h4>  
</div>
```

​[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nCrct/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The countdown plugin uses the class `hasCountdown` to test whether the countdown has already been instantiated, so you should use a different class name.

From jquery.countdown.js:

```
/* Class name added to elements to indicate already configured with countdown.*/
markerClassName: 'hasCountdown'
```